# Use GUID as parameter in one controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, guid

My goal is that I still want to use the default asp.net mvc `id` but I want to use Guid in one controller like this

```
http://example.com/MyController/Index/387ecbbf-90e0-4b72-8768-52c583fc715b
```

This is my route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

MyController right now

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid guid)
{
return View();
}
```

Gives me the error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'guid'
>   of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.Guid)'

I guess it's because I have ID in routes? How can I use GUID as parameters in one controller but `id` in the rest of the application (as default)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just change the name of the parameter from `guid` to `id`:

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
{
    return View();
}
```

When binding the action, ASP.NET MVC inspects the types and the names of the action method and maps those to the parameters that are provided by the request. As the term `id` is used in the route, you have to name the parameter of the action accordingly.

Comment: with this code, always an empty guid is bound to id, even if you pass a valid guid  in query string. you have to add [FromQuery] attribute for the parameter.
    public ActionResult Index([FromQuery]Guid id)
    {
        return View();
    }